# List formatting: combine motion class variable

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

According to MS it's possible to configurate the motion for elements in SharePoint Lists. Is written here [Fluent UI - Motion](https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/fluentui#/styles/web/motion) when I add **ms-motion-slideUpIn** to the class attribute, the corresponding element slides in.
Working, so far so good.

What's not working is combining this with duration and timing classes like **$ms-motion-duration-4**. I can't get this to run. my code is

```
"attributes": {
      "class": "ms-motion-fadeIn $ms-motion-duration-4"
}
```

(Btw, is there an overall list of all classes we can use? I only find examples how to connect things like **ms-fontSize-42**.)

Comment: I just inspected list view page in one of my tenant & seems like `ms-motion-slideUpIn` & `ms-motion-fadeIn` are loaded by default. But I was not able to find any classes starting with `$ms-motion-duration` or `$ms-motion-timing` on page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can only use the classes from fluent UI which are loaded by default on SharePoint list view pages (unless you somehow injected the fluent UI CSS on modern pages, maybe using application customizer).

I just inspected list view page in one of my tenants & observed that classes like `ms-motion-slideUpIn` & `ms-motion-fadeIn` are loaded by default on page. But I was not able to find any classes starting with `$ms-motion-duration` or `$ms-motion-timing` on list view page.

Also, here is list of classes you can use in JSON formatting:

1. [JSON formatting - Predefined classes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#predefined-classes)
2. [SharePoint Online CSS Classes](https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/)

Comment: The `ms-motion-*` are classes that can be applied in formatting. The `$ms-motion-duration-*` and `$ms-motion-timing-*` are CSS variables. Unfortunately, the style properties where you would apply timing and duration are NOT whitelisted for list formatting so there is no way to control those properties with out of the box formatting.

Comment: Thank you Chris for confirming this!